# Why for... of loop doesn't change values inside the array, while the regular for loop does?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, iteration

Consider the following code.

```js
const iterable = [10, 20, 30];

for (let value of iterable) {
  value += 1;
  console.log(value);
}

// 11
// 21
// 31

console.log(('after for...of'), iterable); // [10, 20, 30] - no change

const iterable1 = [10, 20, 30];

for (let i = 0; i < iterable1.length; i++) {
  iterable1[i] += 1;
  console.log(iterable1[i]);
}

// 11
// 21
// 31

console.log(('after regular for...'), iterable1); // [11, 21, 31] - values changed
```

As you see and as was stated in the question, the values in the array didn't change after the `for...of` loop, but did after the regular `for` loop.

After reading [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/statements/for...of) about the `for... of` I was led to believe that(at least in this particular context) it would be identical to the `for` loop, but as you see, this has proven not to be the case. It is especially baffling for me since the article states that

> It invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the ***value*** of each distinct property of the object.

The article proceeds to state that you can reassign values of the iterable(in our case, an array) inside the block.

> You can use `let` instead of `const` too, if you reassign the variable inside the block.

It would seem to me that I lack some critical (maybe even trivial) insight into how the `for...of` works, and I hope you could help me better understand what is going on.

Comment: You can think of `for...of` as a a normal for loop that does `let value = array[index]`. When you change `value` after it is being assigned `array[index]` the value in `array` doesn't change.

Answer (score 4):

In your `for ... of` loop, on each iteration `value` is a **copy** of an element in the array. Thus,

```
value += 1;
```

is critically different from

```
iterable1[i] += 1;
```

The `value += 1;` statement does *work*, and after that `value` will indeed contain a number one greater than an element of the array. However, the element of the array itself remains unchanged.

Consider this simpler case:

```
let x = 0, y;

y = x;
y += 1;
console.log(x);
```

you would see no change to the value of `x`. The variable `y` is also just a copy of the value of `x`, so when `y` changes, `x` is unaffected.

Comment: It's only a copy because the array is storing primitives right? If it were objects then value would be a reference, so modifying value in that case would effect the original array.

Comment: @Shnick well the words to describe that situation get tricky. The variable is still a copy of the *actual* value (a reference to an object), so yes modifying the object it self will be reflected whether you use `value` or the array element to get to the object.  Strictly speaking though, it's still a copy of the value. It's just that you can't do "interesting" things with object references that are like adding one to a number.

Comment: See also: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you are just accessing the value but after after increment you are not setting it back to the array. Since array index is not available while using `for...of` you can use [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries)

```js
const iterable = [10, 20, 30];

for (const [i, v] of iterable.entries()) {
  iterable[i] = v + 1
}
console.log(('after for...of'), iterable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be helpful to look at a `for...of` loop as similar to a function.

Remember, in a function when you pass in an argument that is a primitive data-type, the parameter for that argument will receive a 'copy' of that argument's primitive value. Any changes made to the parameter *will not* effect the outside variable|argument.

And, when you pass in an argument that is an object, the parameter for that argument gets a copy of the address in memory of the object e.g. it will refer to the same object. Any changes made to the parameter *will* effect the outside variable|argument.

The code snippet below demonstrates these two ideas:

```js
primitiveVariable = 1;
obj = {num: 1};

function f(primitive, object) {
  primitive+=1;
  object.num+=1;
  console.log(primitive);
  console.log(object)
}

f(primitiveVariable, obj);

console.log(primitiveVariable);
console.log(obj);
```

A `for...of` loop operates the same:

```js
a = [1, 2, 3];

for (item of a) {
  item += 1;
}

console.log(a);

for (item of a) {
  a[0] = item;
}

console.log(a);
```